# File path keep changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:kAppDatabase];


-(void) copyDataBaseIfNotExist

{
    BOOL success;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];

if(success) return;

//This block will run for the first time only

NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kAppDatabase];

// Make a copy of the file in the Documents folder
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];
db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:self.databasePath];

[self insertDummyData];

NSLog(@"%@ Database path %s ",self.databasePath,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

}

The above code copies the file into the documents folder. Now the first time it saved. The filepath is:

```
811E4F6C-B282-402A-859B-40FA6DBD2B3C/data/Containers/Data/Application/E6F63F62-30F6-4580-BF4D-C16DE2B33292/Documents/AppDatabase.db
```

Second time it accesses from :

```
811E4F6C-B282-402A-859B-40FA6DBD2B3C/data/Containers/Data/Application/48771A22-0616-4162-9DF9-8C5CC4AF6D39/Documents/AppDatabase.db
```

Why does it change every time and shouldn't it be same?

Comment: Why do you care?  You should always use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.

Comment: I wanted to store the path returned in a database so that I would access it later. but document path keeps changing . what could be the solution?

Comment: Don't store the full path, just the part you append.

Answer (score 1):

if you are running your app in iOS8 ,it will keep change the path.
checkout here:http://pinkstone.co.uk/where-is-the-documents-directory-for-the-ios-8-simulator/

Comment: yep running for ios8. What could be the solution?

Comment: check the given link, you may get the answer. With iOS8 and Yosemite, for security reason Apple introduced this technic :)

Comment: Is it just for simulator or for device too?

Comment: Seriously , i have no idea about this, i am facing same issue with WIFI IP and VPN IP address

Comment: This has been what happens forever, if you delete & reload the app.